# Can anyone explain intuitively why increasing the circumference by 1 meter always increases the radius by 15.9cm?

Tags: geometry, intuition, circles

I found the mathematical proof, and it is obviously correct. But how can the increase in radius be constant regardless of the starting circumference? With a very small circle, the increase should be huge but with a massive circle, the difference should end up miniscule shouldnt it? After all, the 1 m is getting distributed over a much larger circumference

Let the radius of the sphere be R and the new radius be R', hence

$2\pi R' = 2 \pi R + 1$

or,

$2\pi(R'-R) = 1$

or, the height $R' - R$ is $1/{2\pi} = 15.9 cms.$

Comment: I think the physical reasoning will still be mathematical!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure if this is appropriate for Physics.SE. It seems to be asking for intuitive mathematical reasoning (!= physical reasoning)

Comment: @Ali I was coming from the POV that this would be related to Newtonian Physics. But yeah, math does make more sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a small circle, the increase is huge *with respect to the small circle*. Basically, for a circle of radius 1cm, the 15.9cm increase is a lot ... with respect to the original circle.

To convince yourself, consider this: When you increase the radius of a 1m radius circle by 1m, the radius doubles, but if you do it to a 100m circle, it just increases by a tiny amount relative to the original radius. So in the case of the larger circle, the increase *seems* much less because the *relative* increase is less, but in both cases the *actual* increase is the same.

It's a similar situation with the 15.9 cm increase. The absolute increase is the same, but the relative increase (which is what our brains find easier to imagine) is much smaller

Comment: Relative vs absolute resolved 80% of my doubt. the remaining 20% is just me not being able to visualise how, adding a constant amount of circumference to any  circumference increases the radius by a constant amount

Answer (score 0):

The radius of a circle is directly related to its circumference. The radius is in proportion to the diameter, which is in proportion to the circumference. Radius multiplied by $2$ gives the diameter, which when multiplied by $π$, gives the circumference, or $2πr$.

Answer (score -1):

Because a circle with a circumference of 1m has a radius of 15.92cm.
So whenever you add 15.9cm to the radius of a circle you add 1m to the circumference.

Or whenever you add 1m to the circumference, you add 15,9cm to the radius.

Because $2\pi \times 0.159155 \approx 1$.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! See, how beautiful formulas I made for you. :-)